# How to find position in large JSON file

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I have a very large JSON file that I am trying to parse through with Eclipse. Unfortunately, I keep getting the error of:

Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 1029.

I downloaded the free version of Liquid Studio to be able to look at the JSON file without crashing. However, I was wondering if anyone knew how to find that particular LEFT BRACE at position 1029 to find it quickly and fix it along with any other possible future occasions in which I may come across other unexpected tokens.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Sounds like you have a malformed JSON file. It'll be hard to fix unless you can spot the issue. A text editor such as vim should be able to open it and let you jump directly to line 1209.

Answer (score 8):

Open NotePad ++ >> Go to language Menu >>josn format >> Copy and paste Json file >>

Then Cntrl+Home >>Cntrl+G >> select Offset >> Enter json position.

Happy Learning .

Answer (score 1):

The offset will be shown in the status line in the upcoming release, Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) which will be released tomorrow (September 18, 2019):

See [Eclipse 4.13 - New and Noteworthy - New features in the Platform and Equinox - Editor status line shows more selection details](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#editor-status-line)

As far as I know, unfortunately, there is no *Go to Offset* command yet similar to the *Go to Line* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) command.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the JSON file with Atom and install the `pretty-json` plugin. Once the plugin is installed, pressing `command-shift-J` (on Mac) will cause Atom to attempt to format your JSON file. If the JSON is malformed, it'll display an error message showing you the bad characters in your JSON.

If you just want to see the characters around where the bad character is, assign the JSON to a string in your favorite language and use substring:

```
String json = "{"some-long": "json-string"}";
// Print the 10 characters before and after the bad character at 1029, which should help you debug
System.out.println(json.substring(1020, 1040));
```